# XAMPP - PHP Going Outside Main Site Folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, dreamweaver

So my site structure looks like this

C:/xampp/htdocs/Testing/index.php

This PHP file includes a code that looks like this

```
<div>     
<?php require 'php/header.php';
?>
</div>
```

in the header.php, it calls for

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Once all this is uploaded to hosted web server it all works because the site can not access files outside the root folder but in XAMPP when previewing my site the code is broken because it is looking for the css/styles.css not in my site folder but in C:/xampp/htdocs/css/ instead of C:/xampp/htdocs/Testing/css/

This is making the preview of my main index.php broken but all the other sub pages like flavors/index.php and locations/index.php work fine. If any one has had this problem or can think of a fix please let me know because it is giving me a headache. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I propose you a solution. Create a VirtualHost in your xampp, and this will probably fix your problem.

In you `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`, add this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/Testing
    ServerName www.testing.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, in your `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\` Open the "hosts" file :

```
127.0.0.1       www.testing.com
```

Finally, in your `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`, scroll to the line VirtualHost and it should look like this :

```
#Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Change your css for this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Restart your xampp server, and go to `www.testing.com` in your browser.

Enjoy it !

Comment: I think document root should be up to the root folder. DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/Testing

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set a basepath?

```
<base href="localhost/Testing">
```

This is probably the most simple solution. 
Just add this rule to your index within the 'head' tags